# Catching Exception in Controller NonFatal

Tags: scala, exception, playframework

Assume I have the following controller method:

```
def getAllRules() = AuthAction("View" on "Rules").async {
   Metrics.measureTime("getAllRules", category = Category) {
     ruleService.getAllRules.map({
       case Nil => NoContent
       case rules => Ok(Json.toJson(rules.toViewRules))
     }).recover {
       case e: Exception => handlerError(s"Failure occurred on getAllRules, ex: ${e.getMessage}", "getAllRules")
     }
   }
}
```

when `handleError` is:

```
def handlerError(err: String, occurredOn: String): Result = {
    Metrics.errorsCounter(occurredOn).increment()
    logger.error(err)
    InternalServerError(Json.toJson(Json.obj("error" -> err)))
}
```

I understood that catching all exceptions is a mistake, and I should catch only `NonFatal` Exceptions.

I wanted to ask:

1. What is a Fatal Exception? How can occur? `VirtualMachineError, InterruptedException, LinkageError, ControlThrowable`
2. Why it's not good to catch all exceptions, but only `NonFatal`?
3. In the case of `Fatal` Exception - how its need to be handled?, code-example would be great with an explanation
4. Just to make sure - If the controller will not catch any Exception, in k8s & docker env, the Pod will be failed with status Error and make a Restart - Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a Fatal Exception? How can occur? VirtualMachineError, InterruptedException, LinkageError, ControlThrowable

Basically, you can conisider fatal errors - those which you can not handle properly. E.g. `VirtualMachineError` or any another `java.lang.Error` identifies problems occured in JVM internals, which you can't do much with: like `AbstractMethodError` - identifies that somehow was invoked method without implementation, which means that the issue in bytecode.
Or famous `OutOfMemmoryError` - usually recommended to not handle, because it might lead to heap corrution or another problems. Let them just crash an app.

> Why it's not good to catch all exceptions, but only NonFatal?
> Because, suing `case NonFatal(e) =>` you avoiding possible problems describe before.
>
> In the case of Fatal Exception - how its need to be handled?,
> code-example would be great with an explanation

You should not catch them - fatal errors your friends and will make troubleshooting easier. Let them crash the app. It is correct approach.

> Just to make sure - If the controller will not catch any Exception, in
> k8s & docker env, the Pod will be failed with status Error and make a
> Restart - Right?

Yes, but make sure you have some `circuit breaker` logic - don't re-start app endless time, if it is does not help. E.g. in case with `AbstractMethodError` - problems with binaries and only way to fix it - re-build or fix dependencies, but restating will only consume resources, without result.

Answer (score 1):

I think that looking at the [`apply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/util/control/NonFatal.scala#L39) method of `NonFatal` is the best to understand it:

```
def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
  // VirtualMachineError includes OutOfMemoryError and other fatal errors
  case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
  case _ => true
}
```

From [Scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html):

> Extractor of non-fatal Throwables. Will not match fatal errors like VirtualMachineError (for example, OutOfMemoryError and StackOverflowError, subclasses of VirtualMachineError), ThreadDeath, LinkageError, InterruptedException, ControlThrowable.

Let's deep dive into each of the exceptions above:

- [`VirtualMachineError`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/VirtualMachineError.java#L36): Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue operating.
- [`ThreadDeath`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadDeath.java#L49): An application should catch instances of this class only if it must clean up after being terminated asynchronously.  If ThreadDeath is caught by a method, it is important that it be rethrown so that the thread actually dies.
- [`InterruptedException`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/InterruptedException.java#L49): Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception.
- [`LinkageError`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/LinkageError.java#L37): Subclasses of {@code LinkageError} indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class.
- [`ControlThrowable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/util/control/ControlThrowable.scala#L43): A parent class for throwable objects intended for flow control. Instances of `ControlThrowable` should not normally be caught.

As you can see, all exceptions are exceptions that the process cannot recover from. Therefore, it is the best to let those exceptions bubble, and terminate the process.

The usage should be(from the `NonFatal` page I attached):

```
try {
  // dangerous stuff
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) => log.error(e, "Something not that bad.")
 // or
  case e if NonFatal(e) => log.error(e, "Something not that bad.")
}
```